# Exception not being trapped in Citrix

Tags: c#, winforms, citrix

I have a windows desktop application written with C# (Windows forms). In the code, there is a part where I use a simple try-catch exception handler. It works as expected in desktops setting, however, when deployed in Citrix it does not work at all. There is an error that I expect to fire there, I catch it and the application keeps running just fine. Anyone seen anything like it?

EDIT:
This is the code that fails. It may not say much since it is just a try catch where I execute code that is related to a specific library.

```
        try
        {
            if (this.model != null)
            {

                if (this.model.Context.GetService<Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Document>().ActivePageReference.ActiveVisualReference != (Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visual)this.model.Visual)
                {
                    this.model.Context.GetService<Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Document>().ActivePageReference.ActiveVisualReference = (Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visual)this.model.Visual; //In certain conditions this line may fail, so I trap it. 
                }                                        
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.Source + " " + exc.Message + "\n" + exc.StackTrace);
        }
```

I added a comment to the line that fails. I trap the error and it works just fine. The thing is that when it is deployed to citrix it fails to trap the error and it actually crashes the application. Thus my inclination to think that it is something related to citrix.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share you code ?

Comment: And you're sure it's occurring there?  Stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to trap the error"? Does catch block execute (WriteLine call)? What type of exception is generated when program is run under Citrix? Is it the same type as the one when program is run locally or not? There are some exceptions in .NET that can not be supressed, for example - ThreadAbortException.

Comment: The most possible reason is that under Citrix your app has lower permissions and accessing some of the exception object properties raise another exception. Wrap catch block in another try-catch and see if it catches the exception from the first catch block

Comment: Zimdanen, yes, I am sure it is happening there. I actually have a log and can see the stack trace originating on the line I comment there. vlad2135 the writeLine actually does not execute in Citrix. I can tell it is coming from that procedure but do not see the writeline stuff. What you mention in your last comment makes more sense. It may be something else in Citrix firing that cannot be executed.